# instrucción adecuada en SQL

Tags: python, sql, sqlite3

estoy creando un programa en Python con sqlite 3, ese programa imprime ciertos datos (insertados anteriormente por el usuario y extraidos del cursor por medio de un ciclo for). El problema es que cuando imprime los datos en la consola se imprimen también las filas y columnas no llenadas  por el usuario y yo solo quiero que se impriman las filas rellenadas, he intentado eliminarlas pero no puedo. Alguien me puede dar un consejo ? adjunto el codigo:

```
try:

        if varCButton1.get()=="On":

            listaTareasFrances=[]

            
            conexion=sqlite3.connect("Devoirs")
            cursor=conexion.cursor()

            cursor.execute(""" SELECT FRANCAIS FROM DEVOIRSETUDIANTS """)

            laTareaFrances=cursor.fetchall()

            for h in laTareaFrances:

                if h!="NULL" and h!="(None,)" and h!=None:


                    listaTareasFrances.append(h)

                    print(listaTareasFrances)

                else:

                    listaTareasFrances.remove(h)

                    print(listaTareasFrances)

    except ValueError:

        messagebox.showwarning("Pas de devoirs", "Vous devez inserer un devoir pour pouvoir acceder dans cet angle")
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar un poco más por favor? No terminé de entender.
Tal vez ayudaría que incluyas una captura de cómo sale ahora, y cómo debería salir.

Comment: Desconozco como realizar consultas SQL en Python, pero si querés filtrar los valores que en la tabla contienen "NULL" o "(None, )", se puede hacer en la consulta SQL. **SELECT francais FROM devoursetudiants WHERE francais IS NOT NULL AND francais <> '(None,)'**

Comment: Muchas Gracias.